# how to send any key from my program to another - in windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to send any key from my program to another - in windows-mobile ?

for ex: if i press 'A' in my program, and i want to send it to another program

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

We need to know a bit more about your goals.  Are you trying to create some form of "keyboard" application? The "proper" way to do this is to create a SIP (Boling has [a good tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5461b.aspx) in his book), which is designed for doing that. Of course that can't be done in managed code.

[PostKeybdMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms911936.aspx) or [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa928103.aspx) are API ways to inject characters into the keyboard stream and can be P/Invoked.

If you are needing to target a *specific" application, then PostMessage is probably how you're going to have to go about it.  If you are trying to target a specific control in a specific app, it gets more challenging because you need that target HWND.